# jQuery: render element to the DOM, then select it with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Trying to understand something here: if I render something to the DOM from javascript, and want to call jQuery methods on it, it behaves differently than if I "re-select" the element from the DOM. Here's a simple example, in CoffeeScript:

```
element = """
  <div id="my_div">TEST!</div>
  """

$('body').html(element)
element.hide() #this doesn't work.
$(element).hide() #this doesn't work either.

$('div#my_div').hide() #this does.
```

So, I seem to be misunderstanding something here. I guess the element variable is just a string and jQuery doesn't understand that it has been added as an element in the DOM.

Is there a different way to insert content into the dom, then, so that it behaves like a normally-selected jQuery object once it has been inserted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the first line doesn't work is because element is a string. The reason the second line doesn't work is because it ends up creating **another** DOM version of the string.

The fix would be to maintain a ref to the DOM version of the element the first time you construct it (in JS):

```
var $elem = $(element);
$elem.appendTo(document.body);
$elem.hide() // should work
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
element = $('<div id="my_div">TEST!</div>');
```